# When to close RxDart stream controller?

Tags: flutter, rxdart

For instance, there is a bloc class

```
class ProductBloc {
  final _productName = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  Stream<String> get productName =>
      _productName.stream;

  Function(String) get changeProductName => _productName.sink.add;
  
  dispose() {
    _productName.close();
    print('bloc disposed');
  }
  ...
```

When and where I have to run `dispose()` to close RxDart stream controller?

Answer (score -1):

you never call the `dispose` method manually. this function calls when your bloc is thrown away from your widget tree.

Comment: But when the bloc is thrown away from a widget tree?

Comment: for example, you navigate to a page that uses a bloc. something like this pseudo-code: `navigator.push(TheBloc(child: PageA()))`. a new instance of `TheBloc` initiates. when you pop the page, this bloc disposes.

Comment: @rozerro This cannot be true, how should the widget know that bloc has a `dispose()` method as it does not implement any interface or is linked to the framework in any way.

Comment: @CodeSpirit to make your bloc usable from your widget you usually use BlocProvider, which you wrap your widget with, right? BlocProvider is a stateful widget that inside its `dispose` method closes the bloc, you can actually see it here: [Link](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/a75a1d804e6b6e0364e2fd3fd572b3796174413a/packages/flutter_bloc/lib/src/bloc_provider.dart#L132)